# changing timepicker title permanently to what you want?

Tags: android

I set title using

```
timePicker.setTitle("sdsd");
```

but when i change the time in the timepicker the title changes to that time and get rid of my title how do i keep my title permanently on the time picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You could set an [onTimeChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener.html) listener and change the title back each time.

2) You could extend TimePicker and change the title yourself each time.

3) You could get the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base) for TimePicker and take it into your project removing the call to change the title

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
private TimePickerDialog prepareDialog(int hour, int minute) {
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity())) {
        @Override
        public void setTitle(CharSequence sequence) {
            super.setTitle("CUSTOM TITLE GOES HERE");
        }
    };
}
```